# Why Firexfox and IE cannot open a link (anchor) inside a <button></button> tag.

Tags: html

Why IE and Firefox cannot open a link inside the button tag, In chrome
it opens the link in same window.

Example:

```
<button type="button"><a href="http://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a></button>
```

Comment: Button is meant to initiate some action. If you are expecting just a redirection, you can remove the button. And if you want the button appearance you can use style sheet with anchor tag to achieve it. Even it chrome you are not supposed to do that. However as per the chrome implementation it can deal with it. It doesn't mean that you can use tags in that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'not allowed to have link inside a button, according to HTML5 specifications

[HTML5 reference from W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element)

> Content model: Phrasing content, but there must be no interactive
>   content descendant.

`a` is interactive content descendant

[Interactive content description](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/content-models.html#interactive-content)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but you should do it like this:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com"><button type="button">stackoverflow</button></a>
```